# Material Change Issue

Tags: animation, materials, animation-nodes

I got an issue regarding animating some objects in blender. There are 3 objects which should switch from a transparent material to a material with emission, one after another. I managed this by using a mixed shader and switching the Fac by keyframes.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

The issue that I can't comprehend or solve is that after the first object switches to material with emission, the other objects get darker and stay like this, without the material changing anything. I rendered the two frames where the issue appears. I think it relates to different lighting conditions. Is there any way to avoid this?

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Hello maybe share a file with your 3 objects? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This might have something to do with [Multiple Importance Sampling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#multiple-importance-sampling) See this nice explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAVxxuT9v_g Try disabling Multiple Importance Sampling for your light objects to see if that helps.

Comment: What are the first two images, just the same material only showing us the factor changing from 0 to 1? Or are those two different materials? It would be interesting to see if there are differences between the materials of the three objects. By the way, why mixing between two shaders? Why not set the _Principled BSDF_ to the same base color as the _Glass BSDF_ and the _Transmission_ to 1? Then you can animate the _Emission Strength_ from 0 to 3 or whatever you want.

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded the file via the link :)
https://blend-exchange.com/b/5eb3sB8r

Comment: Here is frame 104, it seems to work as expected, no? https://zupimages.net/up/23/43/0dd3.jpg

Comment: The problem was, when the first button turns green with emission, the other two are getting a little bit darker. My workaround now was to just place an object with the same emission somewhere else in the scene :D Then the "darker" material will be there from the beginning haha

But thanks for your help! 